# Expanding an existing table in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've got an table in excel with formulae I would like to add data to.

[image: table]

My motivation for this is the fact that tables in excel can dynamically expand to the range of data you add to them, meaning that the formula rows automatically keep up with the amount of data rows.

I'm however having a hard time finding out if this is possible using apache-POI.

One thing I was going to try (see code below) was to expand the `AreaReference` of the table to cover the data, however both `AreaReference(CR,CR2);` (as used in [this](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html) example) and `AreaReference(CR,CR2, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007)` (seen in the apache [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/AreaReference.html%20docs)) give "constructor is undefined".

No idea what is causing that constructor error as I do have `org.apache.poi.ss.util` imported.

The other option on the apache docs `AreaReference(java.lang.String reference)` lets me compile and run but instead gives a "NoSuchMethod" error.

```
        List<XSSFTable> tableList = spreadSheet.getTables();
        CellReference CR = new CellReference(0, 0); 
        CellReference CR2 = new CellReference(5, 2);
        AreaReference my_data_range = new AreaReference(CR,CR2);
        tableList.get(0).setArea(my_data_range);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The reason for the multiple problems while using constructor of `AreaReference` might be that multiple different versions of `apache poi` `jar`s are in class path while compile time and/or run time. Do not mix different `apache poi` versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem using `apache poi` until now is that it is not ready to be used without having detailed knowledge about `Microsoft Office` as such and about the storage of `Microsoft Office` files. There are many things only half way ready and there are regressions often in new versions (bugs occur again which were solved already).

So your requirement: "Expanding an existing table in Excel using Apache POI" is not possible only simply using `apache poi`. One must know that `Office Open XML` files `*.xlsx` are simply `ZIP` archives which can be unzipped. And after unzipping we find `/xl/tables/table1.xml` for storage of the table. This `XML` we can analyzing and comparing it with `XML` which was created using `Excel`'s `GUI`. So we can find problems which results from shortcomings of `apache poi`. Same is with the sheet's `XML` in `/xl/tables/sheet1.xml`.

Also we need to know that `apache poi` builds on the low level classes of `ooxml-schemas`. Partially we need using those classes because of the halfway readiness of `apache poi`. In the following example we need `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` additionally because `apache poi`'s `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.0.jar` has not included `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableFormula` until now. Unfortunately there is no documentation about `ooxml-schemas` public available. So we need downloading the sources and doing `javadoc` our own.

The following example works for me using `apache poi 4.0.0`. If you get problems while compiling or running, the reason might be that multiple different versions of `apache poi` `jar`s are in class path while compile time and/or run time. [Do not mix different apache poi versions](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204). Also, as said already, my code needs [the full jar of all of the schemas ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;

class ExcelExpandingTable {

 static void addRowToTable(XSSFTable table) {

   int lastTableRow = table.getEndCellReference().getRow();
   int totalsRowCount = table.getTotalsRowCount();
   int lastTableDataRow = lastTableRow - totalsRowCount;

   // we will add one row in table data
   lastTableRow++;
   lastTableDataRow++;

   // new table area plus one row
   AreaReference newTableArea = new AreaReference(
                                 table.getStartCellReference(), 
                                 new CellReference(
                                  lastTableRow, 
                                  table.getEndCellReference().getCol()
                                 ),
                                 SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007
                                );

   // new table data area plus one row
   AreaReference newTableDataArea = new AreaReference(
                                     table.getStartCellReference(), 
                                      new CellReference(
                                       lastTableDataRow, 
                                       table.getEndCellReference().getCol()
                                      ),
                                      SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007
                                    );
   
   XSSFSheet sheet = table.getXSSFSheet();
   if (totalsRowCount > 0) {
    //if we have totals rows, shift totals rows down
    sheet.shiftRows(lastTableDataRow, lastTableRow, 1);

    // correcting bug that shiftRows does not adjusting references of the cells
    // if row 3 is shifted down, then reference in the cells remain r="A3", r="B3", ...
    // they must be adjusted to the new row thoug: r="A4", r="B4", ...
    // apache poi 3.17 has done this properly but had have other bugs in shiftRows.
    for (int r = lastTableDataRow; r < lastTableRow + 1; r++) {
     XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r); 
     if (row != null) {
      long rRef = row.getCTRow().getR();
      for (Cell cell : row) {
       String cRef = ((XSSFCell)cell).getCTCell().getR();
       ((XSSFCell)cell).getCTCell().setR(cRef.replaceAll("[0-9]", "") + rRef);
      }
     }
    }
    // end correcting bug

   }

   // if there are CalculatedColumnFormulas do filling them to the new row
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastTableDataRow);
   int firstTableCol = table.getStartCellReference().getCol();
   for (CTTableColumn tableCol : table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList()) {
    if (tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula() != null) {
     int id = (int)tableCol.getId();
     String formula = tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula().getStringValue();
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(firstTableCol + id - 1); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(firstTableCol + id - 1);
     cell.setCellFormula(formula);
    }
   }


   table.setArea(newTableArea);

   // correcting bug that Autofilter includes possible TotalsRows after setArea new
   // Autofilter must only contain data area
   table.getCTTable().getAutoFilter().setRef(newTableDataArea.formatAsString());
   // end correcting bug

   table.updateReferences();

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("SAMPLE_NEW.xlsx")) {
   
   XSSFSheet sheet = ((XSSFWorkbook)workbook).getSheetAt(0);
   XSSFTable table = sheet.getTables().get(0);

   addRowToTable(table);

   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

---

The above was 2018. Now we have 2022.

Using current `apache poi 5.2.2` the code may be like follows:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;

class ExcelExpandingTable {

 static XSSFRow addRowToTable(XSSFTable table) {

   int lastTableRow = table.getEndCellReference().getRow();
   int totalsRowCount = table.getTotalsRowCount();
   int lastTableDataRow = lastTableRow - totalsRowCount;
   int firstTableCol = table.getStartCellReference().getCol();

   // we will add one row in table data
   lastTableRow++;
   lastTableDataRow++;

   // new table area plus one row
   AreaReference newTableArea = new AreaReference(
                                 table.getStartCellReference(), 
                                 new CellReference(
                                  lastTableRow, 
                                  table.getEndCellReference().getCol()
                                 ),
                                 SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007
                                );

   XSSFSheet sheet = table.getXSSFSheet();
   if (totalsRowCount > 0) {
    //if we have totals rows, shift totals rows down
    sheet.shiftRows(lastTableDataRow, lastTableRow, 1);
    //correct all sheet table-reference-formulas which probably got damaged after shift rows
    for (CTTableColumn tableCol : table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList()) {
     if (tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula() != null) {
      int id = (int)tableCol.getId();
      String formula = tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula().getStringValue();
      int rFirst = table.getStartCellReference().getRow() + table.getHeaderRowCount();
      int rLast = table.getEndCellReference().getRow() - table.getTotalsRowCount();
      int c = table.getStartCellReference().getCol() + id - 1;
      sheet.getWorkbook().setCellFormulaValidation(false);
      for (int r = rFirst; r <= rLast; r++) {
       XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
       XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
       cell.setCellFormula(formula);
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
   // if there are CalculatedColumnFormulas do filling them to the new row
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastTableDataRow);
   for (CTTableColumn tableCol : table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList()) {
    if (tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula() != null) {
     int id = (int)tableCol.getId();
     String formula = tableCol.getCalculatedColumnFormula().getStringValue();
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(firstTableCol + id - 1); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(firstTableCol + id - 1);
     cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().setCellFormulaValidation(false); // see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66039
     cell.setCellFormula(formula);
    }
   }
   
   // copy cell styles to the new row from the row above
   row = sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastTableDataRow);
   XSSFRow rowAbove = sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow - 1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastTableDataRow - 1);
   for (CTTableColumn tableCol : table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList()) {
    int id = (int)tableCol.getId();
    XSSFCell cellAbove = rowAbove.getCell(firstTableCol + id - 1); 
    if (cellAbove != null) {
     XSSFCellStyle styleAbove = cellAbove.getCellStyle();
     XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(firstTableCol + id - 1); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(firstTableCol + id - 1);
     cell.setCellStyle(styleAbove);
    }
   }

   // set new table area
   table.setArea(newTableArea);

   // update table references
   table.updateReferences();
      
   return sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("SAMPLE_NEW.xlsx")) {
           
   XSSFSheet sheet = ((XSSFWorkbook)workbook).getSheetAt(0);
   XSSFTable table = sheet.getTables().get(0);

   XSSFRow row = addRowToTable(table);

   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

According to [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025), this code needs `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar` instead of `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` now for run using `apache poi 5.2.2`.

Some bugs are fixed. But there is one new bug when using `XSSFCell.setCellFormula` when formula contains table references. But `XSSFWorkbook.setCellFormulaValidation(false)` avoids this.