# Impossible to delete first row of Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to delete completly the first row of my Excel sheet. However, everytime I launch my code, it erased totaly my sheet and every row becomes blank.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I know this question has already been processed many times, but none of the solution proposed worked on my case. There is something wrong for sure.

```
String exportPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\export.xlsx";

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exportPath));
Workbook export = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
Sheet exportSheet = export.getSheetAt(0);

int lastNum = exportSheet.getLastRowNum();
exportSheet.removeRow(exportSheet.getRow(0));
exportSheet.shiftRows(1, lastNum, -1);

inputStream.close();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(exportPath);
export.write(outputStream);
export.close();
outputStream.close();
```

I need the first row of my sheet to be deleted.

Comment: "There is something wrong for sure." could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: What version of apache poi are you using

Comment: Why find the last populated row if you only want to delete the first row?

Comment: Hi I use the last version of apache poi, 4.0.1.  I want to get the last row num because I need to shift the entire sheet.

Comment: The `shiftRows` does not adjusting references of the cells. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877212/expanding-an-existing-table-in-excel-using-apache-poi/52904452#52904452.

Answer (score 0):

In `apache poi 4.0.1`, the `shiftRows` does not adjusting references of the cells. If row 1 is shifted up, then reference in the cells remain r="A2", r="B2", ... But they must be adjusted to the new row though: r="A1", r="B1", ...

This bug appears in `XSSF` (Office Open XML, `*.xlsx`) only. The binary `HSSF` (BIFF, `*.xls`) does not have this problem.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelDeleteShiftRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "SAMPLE.xlsx";

  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  int lastNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  Row row0 = sheet.getRow(0);
  if (row0 != null) sheet.removeRow(row0);

  sheet.shiftRows(1, lastNum, -1); 
  // After that the sheet is corrupted. The shiftRows does not adjusting references of the cells.
  // If row 1 is shifted up, then reference in the cells remain r="A2", r="B2", ...
  // But they must be adjusted to the new row though: r="A1", r="B1", ...

  // This corrects this. But of course it is unperformant.
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    long rRef = ((XSSFRow)row).getCTRow().getR();
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     String cRef = ((XSSFCell)cell).getCTCell().getR();
     ((XSSFCell)cell).getCTCell().setR(cRef.replaceAll("[0-9]", "") + rRef);
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(outputStream);
  outputStream.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Please file a bug to `apache poi` to get this corrected directly by `apache poi` developer team. This complete example, together with a short `SAMPLE.xlsx` is short enough to be placed as an example to show the problem.