# Unable to delete row using Apache POI because the cell contains email address

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.17 to open xlsx spreadsheet , read the `row =1` (row = 0 is the header that should stay there), store the values in my object, and then remove the `row =1`.

[image]

I expect after removal , `row = 2` will become `row = 1` and `last row` will become `last row -1`.   This is my codes:

```js
    private static void removeRow (String pathToExcel ) throws InvalidFormatException {

        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(pathToExcel);

            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            sheet.shiftRows( 2, lastRowNum, -1);

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToExcel));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```js
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException {
        removeRow(PATH_TO_EXCEL);
    }
```

When removing the row = 1  , I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid CellReference: D3:D21
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.separateRefParts(CellReference.java:395)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:113)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.shiftRows(XSSFSheet.java:3024)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.shiftRows(XSSFSheet.java:2966)
at Sandbox.ExcelReader.removeRow(ExcelReader.java:177)
```

I am not sure why it complains about Invalid CellReference ?

Thanks.

**Updated:**  I find the issue, apparently POI doesn't like the entire column D which contains email address format `testing@testing.com` , once I remove the entire column D , POI doesn't throw exception anymore. I am wondering why it doesn't like email address format.  The spreadsheet must contain email address.

**Updated 2 (After Axel's Suggestion)** :

This will not throw any exception, but also doesn't remove the row. After running this method, my spreadsheet stays as it was before running this method.

```java
    private static void removeRow(String pathToExcel) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(pathToExcel);
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            int rowIndex = 1;
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (row != null) {
                System.out.println(row.getCell(3).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
                System.out.println(row.getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
                sheet.removeRow(row);
                sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
            }

            if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
                System.out.println("Last Row");
                Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                if (removingRow != null) {
                    sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the email address as such but the fact that those cells have links in them. Links have references and the updating those references fails while `shiftRows`. One could call this a bug. But the better approach for deleting row 2 (row index 1) is first to delete the row's content and then second shift the other rows up. The `removeRow` properly removes the link references too.

```
...
  int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
  if (row != null) sheet.removeRow(row);
  sheet.shiftRows(2, lastRowNum, -1);
...
```

This works for me using `apache poi 3.17`. Note `apache poi 4.0.1` has other issues using `shiftRows`. See [Impossible to delete first row of Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197625/impossible-to-delete-first-row-of-excel-sheet/54210605#54210605).

Comment: Thanks Axel. Unfortunately I still see the exception thrown. I print the cell D2 before `sheet.removeRow(row);` & `sheet.shiftRows(1, lastRowNum, -1);` .  Here is the output : `testing@testing.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid CellReference: D3:D21
 at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.separateRefParts(CellReference.java:395)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:113)

Comment: @keylogger: My code is tested and works for me. But what row is `row` in your `sheet.removeRow(row);`? Your `sheet.shiftRows(1, lastRowNum, -1);` shifts row 2 (row index 1) once up. But that would shift row 2 to row 1. But row 1 is your header row though? In your question and my answer it was `sheet.shiftRows(2, lastRowNum, -1);` so row 3 (row index 2) was shifted once up. And before that I had removed row 2 (row index 1).

Comment: Thanks Axel. I updated my method and posted in the original question above. I changed the `rowIndex` to 1, or 2, or 3 without any success.  It doesn't throw any more exception today (not sure why, since I don't make any changes since last time), but it also doesn't remove any row. My spreadsheet stays as it was. Something must be wrong on my side here, but not sure what :(

Comment: @keylogger: Your new code does not write out the changed workbook. It has no `workbook.write` anywhere. Note: I have generated exactly the sheeet you have shown in your screenshot and only changed your first shown code as shown in my answer and it works for me.

Comment: Ahhh, of course ... forgot that part ... Thanks Axel. It works now. The weird part , after executing the codes , I open the xlsx file using Office and it complains `"We found a problem with some content in "file.xlsx". Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes".`  But when I click Yes, the row seems to be removed. I guess it is an issue with office.