# How can I append the existing table?

Tags: apache-poi

As I'm working on an automated data-collector and writer, I am using POI (4.1) to append an existing Excel-File .xlsx
Everything is fine so far, until I realized that the Excel I'm writing to and reading from includes a "Table" from the automated data Import. That means the last Line where I have to append is the last line of the imported table but i want to append the table.

I heared sth about spreadsheets but I'm not concerend that this will solve my problem as I didn't understand it that well.
I tried to enlarge the Table in Excel to write to it but I found out, that the Last line of the table, wether it contains sth or not, is used as the last existing line.

```
/**This Method is is building the XSSFRow out of the String[] array. It works fine, as the Stream
     * is just in another method*/

private void schreibeInWorkbook(String[] zuSchreiben)
    {
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(findSheet(zuSchreiben[1]));

        int lastRow = worksheet.getLastRowNum();

        XSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(++lastRow);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : zuSchreiben)
        {
            try
            {
                obj = Double.parseDouble((String) obj);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);

            if (obj instanceof String)
            {
                obj = ((String) obj).replaceAll("\"", "");
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
            {

                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
            {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
            }
        }
        int r = row.getRowNum();
        Cell c2 = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        c2.setCellFormula(formulaXYZ);
        Cell c3 = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        c3.setCellFormula(formulaXYZ);

    }
```

I thought I could just expand the Excel Table by Hand and add it in there but it always appears in the next line right after the end of it although there are tons of empty lines.
[This is what my JavaCode is adding to Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3r5f.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877212/expanding-an-existing-table-in-excel-using-apache-poi/52904452#52904452

Comment: But where can I add my own values? I tried a couple of things and all of them didn't work.

Comment: Depends on which row and which cell in the table you want insert values. You need get the `XSSFTable`. Then my code shows how to get the `int lastTableDataRow`. And if the need is setting the value of column `A` in last table data row, then: `Row row = sheet.getRow(lastTableDataRow); Cell cell = row.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(0); cell.setCellValue(...);`. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html for methods of `XSSFTable`.