# Copy cell formula automatically while adding new row in excel table using apache POI

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi, xlsx, excel-tables

I have a simple table in excel which has a column serial no with formula `=ROW()-ROW(Member_Data[[#Headers],[S. No.]])`. Whenever I add new row to the table serial no is calculated automatically.when i added new row using Apache POI it didn't copied formula to the next row also style should be copied.

I have set `AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:C8", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);`, which specifies my table range till 8th row.But its not working in any row between 1 to 8.

Currently I am copying 1st row formulas to new row using `setcellformula` as workaround which is working. I need alternate solution which is not dependent on 1st row. My task is only for read operation.

Comment: Show us your code. It might be worth says what version of POI you are using - I remember there were some bugs with row moving in older versions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877212/expanding-an-existing-table-in-excel-using-apache-poi/52904452#52904452

Comment: POI version 4.1.1 FInal